# Don't want to maintain Webview state in android

Tags: android

I have created a webview with javascript interface. While clicking on webview's button i am opening the google play activity, i don't want to maintain the same state after relaunching the app.

App-->webview interface-->opening a new activity for google play-->go back to home-->re lanching the app-->showing the google play activity

Here after relaunching the app don't want to display the google play acitivity, it has to display the webview.

Anyone can help me out this.

Comment: How do you launch the Google Play Activity? Can you provide some code?

Comment: intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google")); startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the Android system's behaviour. A task is a string of activities, and when your app opens Google Play that activity gets added to the task that your app is running. When you click your app from the homescreen Android goes to open up the task that your app was running last and brings up whatever activity was last shown in your task, in this case the Google Play activity.

Have a look at Intent flags: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

I believe FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET may do what you're looking for but haven't played around with it so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to your Intent (as Cathal Comerford mentioned):

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will open the Google Play Activity in its own Task instead of your App's Task. So if you relaunch your App it won't show the Google Play page.

Comment: Thank Floern that works fine. It has created the newtask for google play